# nfs-kernel-server wont start after update in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, kernel, mount, nfs

I am working on a project that requires a nfs-kernel-server, and after updating yesterday the nfs-kernel-server will no longer start. After uninstalling / reinstalling, it now crashes at install with:

```
A dependency job for nfs-server.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nfs-kernel-server, action "start" failed.
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Feb 02 16:07:49 Bone0 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Feb 02 16:07:49 Bone0 systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 02 16:07:58 Bone0 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Feb 02 16:07:58 Bone0 systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Failed to start nfs-kernel-server, ignoring.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.11) ...
```

What can I do to get things running again?

```
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Feb 02 17:57:32 Bone0 systemd[4180]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Feb 02 17:57:32 Bone0 systemd[4180]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Feb 02 17:57:32 Bone0 systemd[4180]: Reached target Sockets.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Feb 02 17:57:32 Bone0 systemd[4180]: Reached target Basic System.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Feb 02 17:57:32 Bone0 systemd[4180]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Feb 02 17:57:32 Bone0 systemd[4180]: Startup finished in 217ms.
-- Subject: User manager start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The user manager instance for user 1001 has been started. All services queued
-- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
-- up or be started at any later time.
-- 
-- Startup of the manager took 217776 microseconds.
```

Comment: What does `journalctl -xe` say?

Comment: i edited my post and added the journalctl but does not seam to be of much help at least to me... hope this helps you. thank you for the reply

Comment: This appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1590799

Comment: the link above seams to be a similar issue yes but it does not contain a fix listed for Bionic and seams the last comment made was 2018 3 16 making this almost a year old ... sorry for being confused but if this is a bug has it been reported for a current ubuntu server 18.04 or does it matter

Comment: It says "fix released" so if you're still having a problem, it shouldn't be this bug. Voting to leave the question open for now

Comment: Yes the nfs-kernel-server is still not starting, not really sure what to do but wait for an update that will fix it, unless some one has an idea how to correct the issue

Comment: This project started back November of 2018 and i have spent way to much time messing with the nfs-kernel-server....  at first install it would fail to start .. searching for answers to why i had this issue i installed and reinstalled as well as trying every thing that i could find for a fix.. after about a month or so of that i decided to give it a try again only to have the same issues, after a few more days i did get it to install and work however i had new issues with the number of clients that could connect at one time.. a few more weeks it started to work after a resent update.

Comment: for about 3 weeks it was working fine and suddenly once again after an update im back to square one.. just for fun i tested out the Ubuntu 18.10 and sure enough it seams to be working fine.. cant tell you how frustrating this adventure has been with the nfs system in Ubuntu ... after 4 months of head shaking and hair pulling my project is still incomplete, i have decided to use another distribution that does not have this issue.

Comment: a true disapointment